# Get all input of form from a html-string with jQuery - No matter which level they are

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, input, children

I want to extract out of an html string all forms and their input fields. In order to do this, I've written the following code:

```
var html = $.parseHTML("<html><form id="Form1"><div><input name="Input1"></div></form></html>");
$(html).find('form').each(function(e) {
    var FormElement = $(this);

    $(FormElement).find('input, textarea').each(function(e) {
        consolge.log($(this).attr('name') + " is an input field of a form with the the ID: " + $(FormElement).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Sadly, this extracts only the children input fields of the form. The input fields, which are in a div, which is in a form are not affected by the scanning.

(working example: html -> form -> input)

(not working example: html -> form -> div -> input)

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but, If you're calling `var FormElement = $(this);` you've already created the collection, you dont need `$(FormElement).find` ,  you probably want `FormElement.find` there

Comment: I don't see how the code snippet you posted works at all given that the quotes are mismatched in the HTML string, and the `find('form')` won't return anything as `html` *is a reference* to the `form` element. If you fix those problems, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nqpk9t1w/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code to use (html).each()

```
//with multipule forms
var html = jQuery.parseHTML("<html><form id='Form1'><div><input name='Input1'></div></form><form id='Form2'><div><input name='Input2'></div></form></html>");

jQuery(html).each(function(e) {

    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery(this).find('input, textarea').each(function(e) {
        //that will output for every input and textarea
        console.log(jQuery(this).attr('name') + " is an input field of a form with the the ID: " + id );

    });
});
```